# How to split bibliography into Online references and Offline references

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

I would like to split bibliography list into a list with @misc tags, where all url's references are and all other tags for offline reference list.
How is it possible to do it?
I have snippet of a template that should make it possible:

```
  \ifdefined\bibheadingonline
  \defbibheading{online}{\section*{\bibheadingonline}}
  \else
  \defbibheading{online}{\section*{Online References}}
  \fi
  \ifdefined\bibheadingoffline
   \defbibheading{offline}{\section*{\bibheadingoffline}}
  \else
   \defbibheading{offline}{\section*{Printed References}}
  \fi

  \defbibfilter{online}{%
    \( \type{online} \)}

  \defbibfilter{offline}{%
    \( \not \type{online} \)}
```

but it doesn't work for me. I am new in Latex so I am using a template which was defined not by myself.. I will be glad for any help. If needed, I can upload a part of my thesis for test purposes on a server. Btw. I am using MikeTex 2.9 with TeXnicCenter 2.0 Alpha 3

Comment: Welcome at tex.sx! The code snippets seem to require the `biblatex` package, and it may well be that your template doesn't use `biblatex`. You need to provide more information about the template you use. Note that you should try to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), not a part of your thesis.

Comment: Note that if you are allowed to use (switch to) `biblatex` for your thesis, the answer to your question is very easy - splitting bibliographies by type is one of the package's standard features.

Comment: could you please provide a sample of sorting the bib through biblatex? It's to complicated to shorten my sample...

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simple example of splitting a bibliography by type using `biblatex`. (I used the `filecontents` package to make the example compilable, but it is not necessary for the solution.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@book{Knu86,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The \TeX book},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography[title={Books},type=book]

\printbibliography[title={Other References},nottype=book]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but I think the way the Pamp described it, it would be `nottype=misc` and `type=misc` (even though it might be better to use `@online` for online resources).